# Is there a built-in pandas method to compare a Series of Timestamps to an Interval

Tags: pandas

I have a series of Timestamps, and I want to test to see if they fall within a global Interval. I feel like there should be a natural pandas API to achieve what I have done here. The only way I could find is to use the `between` function:

```py
df['end_date'].between(MY_INTERVAL.left, MY_INTERVAL.right)
```

but that misses out the subtleties around the `closed_left` or `closed_right` properties of the Interval. Is there something better?

Things I have tried:

```py
df['end_date'].isin(MY_INTERVAL) # raises as it expects a collection as argument
```

```py
pd.IntervalArray(df['end_date'], df['end_date']).overlaps(MY_INTERVAL) 
# works feels backward to create an array just for this!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no specific pandas api for this, but one way that respects the closedness of the interval:

```
df['end_date'].map(MY_INTERVAL.__contains__)
```

Thanks to nmay123 here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40243

Answer (score 0):

No sure it fits exactly your needs, but I would do:

```
s = df['end_date']
s.where(s >= '2020-01-09').where('2020-02-15' > s)
```

or

```
df.query("'2020-01-02' <= end_date < '2020-01-17'")

df.query("@lower_bound <= end_date < @upper_bound")
```

to directly select the data in my interval.